# New tab in Terminal.app does not open in same directory/bash fails (Mountain Lion)

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

Basic problem: When I open a new tab in terminal, bash fails with the following error output:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `exec -la (null) (null) -1'

[Process completed]
```

In preferences, I have new tabs set to open with same settings/directory.

I've been messing around learning to customize the bash prompt area, actually in an attempt to fix this problem, but to no avail. I messed around with /etc/bashrc before I realized I should do that by user, I've reset that file to look like this:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
  return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
# Tell the terminal about the working directory at each prompt.
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ] && [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
   update_terminal_cwd() {
       # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
       # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
       # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
       local SEARCH=' '
       local REPLACE='%20'
       local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
       printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
   }
   PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

Finally, my ~/.bash_profile looks like this:

```
source /etc/bashrc

export PATH=~/Code:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin.

export CLASSPATH=~/Programs/:~/Programs/bailey.jar:~/Programs/labs/:.
export PYTHONPATH=~/dm/:~/Code/Git/.:.
```

If anyone can give me any suggestions, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Looks like `update_terminal_cwd()` is throwing an error.  What is this function you are trying to call?

Comment: @thecoloryes Do you know what the escape sequence `\e]7;` does? For me, it blanks out all the input/output on the console until the shell receives a `Enter` key. Are you trying to colorize the output of `printf`?

Comment: @AtlasWegman I don't know what that function does. The bashrc file is exactly the way it was before I changed anything, so the only way that method would have been define is by OSX itself, or by the installation of something that decided it had a reason to edit that file.

Comment: @Samveen I'm not sure what it's intended to do. Again, this is what the file looked like before I started editing colors -- I have a line in my .bash_profile that sets up the terminal to look the way I want it: `export PS1="\[\e]2;\w\a\e[33;40m\]\W>\[\e[0m\] "` which prints the full pwd to the title of the Terminal window and the name of the directory I'm currently in, followed by >, in yellow.

Comment: @thecoloryes I would say best way to work out your issues is go line by line commenting/uncommenting things out.  It's hard for me (or anyone else) to test because of all the system dependent info (paths, scripts, etc)

Comment: I found that setting up the $LOAD variable in a custom way in .bashrc will cause your Terminal not to properly setup the default path. Once I removed my $LOAD variable from the .bashrc, Terminal loaded the new tabs in the expected path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem too, and discovered that I had accidentally changed a setting in the "Startup" tab of the Terminal preferences. The setting was "Shells open with: Command (complete path): ."

I changed it back to "Shells open with: Default login shell" and that solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to the (already very helpful) thread: I'm running Terminal 2.5, and there is now a setting called "New windows open with:";

"Same working directory"

should be chosen in favor of

"Default Working Directory".